# Find object from collection of object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class

```
public class ABC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Enum Msg { get; set; }
}
```

and collection of this class and single object

```
List<ABC> objColl = new List<ABC>();
ABC obj = new ABC();
```

Assume collection have items and i am trying to find single object which already exists in collection. 
i want to find a single object inside that collection whether it exists or not.

I had already tried

```
var res = objColl.contains(obj);
```

it always return false. i dont want compare each property of object or loop.

Comment: you have to override equals method in ABC class

Comment: `i dont want compare each property of object` <= So how will your code know if 2 instances are equal or not? You will have to somehow define that logic somewhere in your code, either as needed or an equality override or an comparer implementation.

Comment: Is it safe to assume, that if the objects have the same `Id`, they are equal, or do all properties of the object have to be equal?

Comment: Hash Set is best possible solution, and yes you should override ABC equals and GetHashCode. If you need to process Contains - always try to use O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Any` with your criteria:

```
bool res = objColl.Any(s => s.Id == obj.Id);
```

if you want to use `Contains` then override `Equals()`.

Comment: As OP said `i dont want compare each property of object or loop`

Comment: @RandRandom Alright, edited to accommodate your comment.

Comment: @Aomine Can you implement the code using `IEquatable` for this posted question?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Contains()`, it searches for an item in the collection that is equal to the argument you've provided. Since you have not overridden `Equals()`, it uses the default implementation.

You have two options:

1. Override `Equals()` in class `ABC` to specify checking only the properties you want to check;
2. Use LINQ: `objColl.Any(e => e.[some property] == obj.[some property])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

```
var res = objColl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == obj.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = objColl.Where(s=>s.Id == obj.Id).Any();
```

Comment: As OP said `i dont want compare each property of object or loop`

Comment: @RandRandom, His question might points not to loop but his requirement is to check the single entity is present or not. So this is the solution i have provided.